# resolution dependent mobile template

Tags: javascript, html, css, screen-resolution

I am developing a small mobile page which supposed to be visible only for mobile devices.
But it should fit all Android & iPhone devices and their resolutions.

The template includes table and couple of images which should shrink in percentage in relation to the ratio of resolution change

what i basically need is a tip for smart CSS code which will consider the resolution and will pick from couple of different stylesheets i will create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect exact device using JS and generate stylesheet link for it.

```
//Detect mobile devices
var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())),

//Detect only iPhone
iphone = (/iphone/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));

//Apply stylesheet for mobile devices
if(mobile){
   var cssLink = document.createElement("link");
   cssLink.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
   cssLink.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
   cssLink.setAttribute("href", "css/mobile.css");
   document.head.appendChild(cssLink);
}

//Apply stylesheet for iPhone only
if(iphone){
   var cssLink = document.createElement("link");
   cssLink.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
   cssLink.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
   cssLink.setAttribute("href", "css/mobile.css");
   document.head.appendChild(cssLink);
}
```

Or detect all mobile devices using Media Query `max-device-width`:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
     /* CSS for mobile */
}
```

Notice that I set `max-device-width` to `480px`. This is because of mobile devices screen measurements, it's in **reference pixels** which is bigger than actual device pixel.
For example both **iPhone 3** and **4** has device width `320px` in both landscape and portrait modes. Some **Android** devices returns device width `480px`.

Comment: in your second method, how would i go about doing ranges from one range of resolutions to another.
the problem with the first method is that even in the iphone there are 2 different resolutions (iphone 4 & 3gs)

Comment: You don't need to do that. Your web page would be scaled to fit in those 320px. Read this article to get better understanding of what I'm talking about - [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html)

Comment: all my problems were solved once i added the 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320">
this set the viewport for all devices to be as small as posible and allowed for larger devices to stretch the viewport to fit it's needs thanks for the article dude it tought me so much!